# MinHight for an expandable card item in lazy column in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Card as an expandable item in LazyColumn, the initial height I want is 50dp, and the max is WrapContaintHeight, I'm trying playing with Modifiers to set the min and the max, here is what I did

```
.height(50dp)
.heightIn(min = 50dp, max = WrapContaintHeight)
```

But it always previews the card height like WrapContaintHeight as the initial height, what I want is the initial height to be 50dp, and when I expand it by clicking on the card to be WrapContaintHeight, I already have a code to control the expand state

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a boolean variable for click to item.

```
.height(if(isFullSize) 100.dp else 50.dp)
```